# Javascript reading local file to UInt8Array fast

Tags: javascript, performance, io, uint8t

How to read local binary file to UInt8Array fast. in below code

```
function readAllBytesAsUInt8Array(path) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", path, false);
    req.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=binary-data");
    req.send(null);
    if (req.status !== 200) {
        console.log("error");
        return null;
    }
    var text = req.responseText;
    var resultArray = new Uint8Array(text.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length;i++){
    resultArray[i] = (text[i].charCodeAt() & 255) & 255;
    }
    return resultArray.buffer;
 }
```

`var text = req.responseText;` is executed less than a second,meanwhile this part

```
var resultArray = new Uint8Array(text.length);
for(var i = 0; i < text.length;i++){
    resultArray[i] = (text[i].charCodeAt() & 255) & 255;
}
```

takes around 10sec for 50MB of binary file, 
*Is there a way to read binary file to UInt8Array faster ?*

Comment: just wondering, do you really need to do `var resultArray = new Uint8Array(text.length);`. ? JavaScript doesn't ask for you to predefine the array size for it. just say `resultArray = [];` and fill it just like you fill yours

Comment: Why do you not set `.responseType` of `XMLHttpRequest()` to `"arraybuffer"`?

Comment: it will be more slower as i push each time to the array it will have to reallocate larger memory for every byte appending

Comment: @guest271314 then what is the right way to convert from arraybuffer to uint8array ? var z = new Uint8Array(buffer) ?

Comment: Have you tried using `FileReaderSync()` and transferring the object to avoid copying the object?

Comment: @ guest271314 it says This interface(FileReaderSync) is only available in workers as it enables synchronous I/O that could potentially block.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `.responseType` of `XMLHttpRequest()` to `"arraybuffer"`, then pass `ArrayBuffer` instance to `new Uint8Array()`. Alternatively you can use `fetch()` and `Response.arrayBuffer()` or `FileReaderSync()` within `Worker` to transfer the `ArrayBuffer` to main thread without copying the `ArrayBuffer`.

```
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
let buffer = req.response;
let u = new Uint8Array(buffer);
```

Comment: are  `req.response` and
`(new Uint8Array(buffer)).buffer` the same thing ? as the method returns `return resultArray.buffer;`

Comment: Yes, `req.response` is an `ArrayBuffer`

Comment: let u = new Uint8Array(buffer); throws exceptions as  Uint8Array() expects first argument as length

Comment: @user818117 No exception is thrown here at either Firefox or Chromium when passing an `ArrayBuffer` to `Uint8Array()`. At which browser was an exception thrown? Can you reproduce the exception at jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder)! TextEncoder takes a stream of code points as input and emits a stream of bytes.

Here is your new code :)

```js
function readAllBytesAsUInt8Array(path) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", path, false);
    req.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=binary-data");
    req.send(null);
    if (req.status !== 200) {
        console.log("error");
        return null;
    }
    var text = req.responseText;
    var encoder = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
    var resultArray = encoder.encode(text);
    return resultArray.buffer;
 }
```

See how that works, should be a lot faster.

Comment: textencoder doesnt work on some browsers like IE,Safari, meanwhile i tested it has the similar performance with above code